# Is it possible to increase size of storage for Devpro sandbox?

Tags: sandbox, developer-edition, storage-limit

Is it possible to increase the storage size from 1Gb to something larger for Dev-pro Sandbox. Is my only option to change to Full or Partial Copy Sandbox?

Answer (score 4):

If changing to Partial/Full copy sandbox is not an option for you, I'd suggest logging a case to Salesforce support and describing your situation.